# Python Tkinter Toplevel not the active window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

I have a Python Program that opens a Toplevel window which is working I just wanted to know if there is an option to set the Toplevel window window to be active once it has been opened because at the moment it is still showing the parent window as the active window after opening it.

The python code (Python 3.4.1)

```
from tkinter import *

class cl_gui:

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title("DataBox")

        menu = Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menu)

        menu_users = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Users", menu=menu_users)
        menu_users.add_command(label="View", command=self.f_openUsers)

    def f_openUsers(self):

        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("Users")

root = Tk()
app = cl_gui(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set focus onto the new `Toplevel` widget as follows:

```
def f_openUsers(self):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Users")
    top.focus_set()  # <- add this line
```

See e.g. [this handy `tkinter` guide](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_set-method).

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to lock the Toplevel window inside the parent element? to prevent it from being dragged away from the parent? just checking

Comment: @Trent what do you mean *"locked inside"*? Are you talking about a parent-child window relationship? I haven't done that in Tkinter, so off the top of my head I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Just to stop the Toplevel window from being dragged outside of the extents of the parent window. It will have to be another question because i think it's a different issue

Comment: @Trent I think there are already questions on Tkinter parent-child relationships, I suggest you spend some time on research first